# Hibernate mapping resource locate in the separate jar

Tags: hibernate, mapping, entity, hibernate-mapping, hibernate.cfg.xml

I have separate jar file has contain hibernate entity mapping and mapping directly. My Hibernate confg (cgf.xml) placed in another jar file. And as result I catch exception "resource: com/iceleads/data/Test.hbm.xml not found".

Example:

```
entities.jar 
   com.package.entity.TestEntity.java
   com.package.entity.TestEnity.hbm.xml

mainUsage.jar
   com.package.main.MainClass.java - there are I get session factory
      SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();

   com.package.main.hibernate.cfg.xml

   in HibernateUtil 
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();

  in hibernate.cfg.xml
       <mapping resource="com/package/entity/TestEntity/Test.hbm.xml"/>
```

entities.jar in mainUsage.jar classpath

Please suggest me how I can configure hibernate.cfg.xml to use separate jar with entities.

Thanks a lot!

Artem

Comment: your example is incorrect. entities.jar contains a file named `TestEntity.hbm.xml` whereas the hibernate.cfg.xml maps a file named `Test.hbm.xml`... Coincidence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use method `addJar()` when creating a new Configuration.

```
sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml")
   .addJar(new File("/path/to/jar")).buildSessionFactory();
```

Answer (score 0):

Including the path of the mapping file into the mapping resource. For instance, use `<mapping resource="com/example/test/test.hbm.xml"/>`, and `test.hbm.xml` is located in the package `com.example.test` inside the jar file.

This will serve the purpose.